# C# Deleting a Event Handler while program is in use

Tags: c#

is there a way to remove an event handler while the program is running?

```
textBox1.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                JRPC.SetMemory(rgh, 0xc035261d, reverseBytes(textBox1.Text));
                JRPC.SetMemory(rgh, 0xc035261c, getBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text + "\0")));
            };
```

I have the code above to real time edit the players Gamertag on Xbox. When a checkbox it checked it will discover the event handler. but when I uncheck it I need it to remove this event handler I figured that I'd just do this (See below)

```
textBox1.TextChanged += (s, a) =>
            {

            };
```

But I want to know if there is a proper way to delete the event handler all together instead of leaving an open handler to do nothing.

Comment: Um... += just adds another handler (there can be many).  You're better off making an actual method that you can readily -= when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the invocation list of an event form within the class, but in your case you can only **unsubscribe** event handlers from it.

Since you're using anonymous methods you cant do that either, you need to keep a reference of the method somewhere, later you can use the `-=` operator to remove it from the invocation list.

You can extract your anonymous method to a named method like this:

```
private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    JRPC.SetMemory(rgh, 0xc035261d, reverseBytes(textBox1.Text));
    JRPC.SetMemory(rgh, 0xc035261c, getBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text + "\0")));
}
```

Than you will subscribe it to the event like this:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += MyMethod;
```

If you want to remove it and no longer call it when the event is invoked:

```
textBox1.TextChanged -= MyMethod;
```

Comment: Could you explain more on how to do that i've been looking around and found some stuff but im very confused on how remove it.

Comment: @areed99 added example of how you can do that.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you and I better understand what I was doing wrong thanks to your examples I appreciate it!